# Consumir Web Service SGS Banco Central Brasil - Cotação dólar

Tags: java, web-service, soap

Consegui gerar o (java) cliente no Eclipse, a patir do WSDL disponível em https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/JSP/sgsgeral/FachadaWSSGS.wsdl.

Foram geradas as seguintes classes:

```
package br.gov.bcb.pec.sgs.casosdeuso.ws.comum;  
    WSValorSerieVO  
    WSSerieVO  

package br.gov.bcb.www3.wssgs.services.FachadaWSSGS  
    interface FachadaWSSGS   
    interface FachadaWSSGSService  
    classe FachadaWSSGSServiceLocator  
    classe FachadaWSSGSProxy  
    classe FachadaWSSGSSoapBindingStub
```

Minha dúvida agora é como instanciar essas classes e utilizar o serviço. 
Meu objetivo é pegar a cotação do dólar em uma data especifica `dd-mm-aaaa`

Alguém pode dar uma força?

Creio que seria algo próximo a:

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceException {    
    FachadaWSSGSProxy proxy = new FachadaWSSGSProxy();
    FachadaWSSGSServiceLocator service = new FachadaWSSGSServiceLocator();
    FachadaWSSGSSoapBindingStub stub = (FachadaWSSGSSoapBindingStub) service.getPort(proxy.getEndpoint(),FachadaWSSGSService.class );       
    try {
        System.out.println(stub.getValor (1,"24/01/2017").toString());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Porem isto não funciona.

Comment: Olá Itamar, poste mais detalhes sobre seu problema. Você gerou o código Java como? O Eclipse permite gerar clientes no padrão do wsimport / JAX-RS (wsimport), Padrão Axis (WSDL2Java ), etc. A chamada que você procura é `getValor` com `in0` = 1 (Código da série da taxa de câmbio)  e `in1` = data no formato `dd/MM/aaaa`

Comment: Para mais detalhes sobre o WSSGS veja a [página de ajuda](https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/JSP/sgsgeral/sgsAjuda.jsp#SA)

Comment: Caro Anthony, Gerei o client no padrão Apache Axis e Client Type = Java Proxy. A minha dúvida é como instanciar o Service e o Stub para conseguir utilizar o metodo getValor.

Comment: O que exatamente não funcionou? Edite a pergunta e cole o stack trace do erro.

Comment: Na nem dá pra executar, pois o trecho de código postado acima, foi apenas um exemplo de como imagino que seria a instanciação das classes, mas não tenho  a menor ideia da forma correta de se fazer.

Comment: Itamar, eu não estou percebendo o problema... Infelizmente existe mais uma de uma maneira correta de usar o cliente. Você está receoso de executar o seu código (se der errado nada de mal vai acontecer)? Ou está procurando por exemplos para comparar com sua versão? Segue um [exemplo trivial usando o Proxy](https://github.com/wmixvideo/cotacao/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fincatto/cotacao/ws/WSConsulta.java) e [outro usando Locator](https://github.com/joaolce/series-bcb/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/sunlive/series/service/SeriesService.java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gerei um JAR com contendo as classes disponiveis em : (https://github.com/wmixvideo/cotacao), e depois instanciei normalmenteo objeto WSConsulta, passando os parametros desejados.

```
System.out.println(" dolar: "+(String.valueOf(new WSConsulta().getCotacao(Indice.DOLAR_COMPRA, LocalDate.of(2017, 01, 10)))));
```

Funcionaou perfeitamente.

OBs: Deve-se tomar cuidado com as consultas em dias nao uteis, pois retorna null.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia amigo!
Você deve implementar dessa forma:

```js
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           FachadaWSSGSProxy proxy = new FachadaWSSGSProxy();
            try {
                System.out.println(proxy.getValor (1,"24/01/2017").toString());
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
    }

}
```